# Scrapy selector for nodes between <br /> tags

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, separator

I have HTML code like this

```
<div>
  Foo <span>Bar</span><br />
  Baz<br />
  <b>Foobar</b> Quux
</div>
```

Now I'd like to process the nodes separated by `<br />` tags like this:

```
nodes  = sel.xpath("???")
my_foo = nodes[0] # contains Foo <span>Bar</span>
my_bar = nodes[1] # contains Bar
my_fb  = nodes[2] # contains <b>Foobar</b> Quux
```

Is there some XPath or CSS expression that will do this or do I have to iterate over all child nodes of `<div>`, building an array in the process for each node that is not a `<br>`?

Comment: For this example, `sel.xpath("//div/text() | //div/*/text()")` gets close. Extracting gives me an array `[u'\nFoo ', u'Bar', u'\nBaz', u'Foobar', u' Quux\n']`.

Comment: Yea, but I want Foo and Bar grouped into one, Baz alone, Foobar and Quux grouped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I can think of is this:

```
[sel.xpath('''.//div/node()[count(preceding-sibling::br)=%d]
                           [not(self::br)]''' % i).extract()
 for i in range(0, len(sel.xpath('.//div/br'))+1)]
```

which gives you:

```
[[u'\n  Foo ', u'<span>Bar</span>'],
 [u'\n  Baz'],
 [u'\n  ', u'<b>Foobar</b>', u' Quux\n']]
```

which gives you lists of node between the `<br/>` elements under `<div>` (counting the `<br>`s and looking for nodes that have `<br>`s before (none, then 1, then 2))